# How to find and replace across multiple documents using Adobe Brackets

Tags: adobe-brackets

ive decided to give the text editor [brackets] a trial. Im just wondering is there a way to find and replace in all open documents using brackets ?

I can see a find and a replace option, but ive got to hunt down alot of content across multiple pages.

I cant seem to find a short cut or an option from any of the drop down menus to replace all matches across multiple files.

any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5):

*Update:* To use this feature now that it's available, just choose Find > Replace in Files. You can also right-click any folder in the left-hand pane and choose Replace In... to only replace within that subtree of your project.

---

*Original answer:*

This feature (replacing across multiple files at once) is not available yet, but it's currently under development and will probably ship in the next release of Brackets, Sprint 40. You can track its progress by following the [Replace Across Multiple Files card on Trello](https://trello.com/c/NbNEOs4S/264-replace-across-multiple-files). (Note: once it ships that link will break, because the card will be moved onto the [Brackets History](https://trello.com/b/RHzQZKTv/brackets-history) board).